# Keep red star displayed page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What’s currently happening is that based on user selection of preferred way of communication from radio buttons a red star appears, for example if they select preferred way of communication is value TelephoneNo a red star shows near “Type in your telephone no” and "confirm telephone no", else this gets hidden when they select a different radio button i.e. preferred way of communication is email. However, what the issue is that if they for example select TelephoneNo the red star appears near “Type in your telephone no” and “confirm telephone no” and if I enter text in " Type in your telephone no " and leave the confirmation box blank and press submit on the form the red stars disappear. I want to keep these red starts displayed, I think I have to call this function again, please advise?

```
 $('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').click(function () { //.communication class passed input name == model public communication
        if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNo") { //if value TelephoneNo selected in model
            $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
            $('.redstar').show(); //shows red star when Mobile option is selected
        } else {
            $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
            $('.redstar').hide(); //Hides red star
        }

        if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNoAlternative") {  //if value == to TelephoneNoalternative
            $('.confirmalttelno').show(); //show confirm alt tel no text box
            $('.redstaralttel').show(); //shows red star when Alt telephone option is selected
        } else {
            $('.confirmalttelno').hide(); //else hide it
            $('.redstaralttel').hide(); //Hides red star

        }

    });
```

Comment: You want to keep this on page reload ? if yes you have to store data in `localStorage`

Comment: can you also show your "submit" function. Also importantly are you allowing the user to submit the form with empty "confirmation box" or do you want to stop submitting if fields are not valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your full code this is a guess. But I give it a try anyway.

The function is wrote is bind to a click function. So it will only fire when you click on the item. After the form is submitted, you want to see (on page load) if the stars should be shown or not.

So add this onload function:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').val() == "TelephoneNo") { //if value TelephoneNo selected in model
        $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
        $('.redstar').show(); //shows red star when Mobile option is selected
    } else {
        $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
        $('.redstar').hide(); //Hides red star
    }

    if ($('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').val() == "TelephoneNoAlternative") {  //if value == to TelephoneNoalternative
        $('.confirmalttelno').show(); //show confirm alt tel no text box
        $('.redstaralttel').show(); //shows red star when Alt telephone option is selected
    } else {
        $('.confirmalttelno').hide(); //else hide it
        $('.redstaralttel').hide(); //Hides red star

    }

});
```

Or even better, combine the both:

```
function checkComm() {
    if ($('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').val() == "TelephoneNo") { //if value TelephoneNo selected in model
        $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
        $('.redstar').show(); //shows red star when Mobile option is selected
    } else {
        $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
        $('.redstar').hide(); //Hides red star
    }

    if ($('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').val() == "TelephoneNoAlternative") {  //if value == to TelephoneNoalternative
        $('.confirmalttelno').show(); //show confirm alt tel no text box
        $('.redstaralttel').show(); //shows red star when Alt telephone option is selected
    } else {
        $('.confirmalttelno').hide(); //else hide it
        $('.redstaralttel').hide(); //Hides red star

    }
};
$(function () { checkComm(); });
$('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').click(function () { checkComm(); });
```